# Conflit between so dynamic libraries (libvlc.so and another one)

Tags: linux, video, libvlc

I am developing a cross-platform (linux and windows) application that uses libvlc.so and an intern library libVideo.so I don't have the source code and can't edit/recompile.

libvlc.so is working alone. But if I create and object `MyPrivateLibrary::Video video;`
Then libvlc cannot decode my video. I think the conflit is with libavcodec but I have no idea how everything works. Instead of having a video decode and displayed, I got those vlc error messages:

> [0xaed01210] avcodec decoder error: cannot open codec (H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10))
>
> [0xaed01210] main decoder error: no suitable decoder module for fourcc `h264'. VLC probably does not support this sound or video format.
>
> [0xaed01210] main decoder error: Pas de décodeur approprié pour le format
>
> [0xaed01210] main decoder error: VLC ne supporte probablement pas le format audio ou vidéo « h264 ». Malheureusement il n'y a rien à faire.

Someone could tell me how I can fixe that? I think it's something to do which so are loaded in which order. Maybe vlc needs libavcodec-extra-53 while livVideo.so uses only libavcodec.